# PhpMyAdmin not recognising php version 8.2.4 on macos Ventura

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin using homebrew. I followed all the instruction that were listed on the homebrew website. When I open localhost://phpmyadmin, the following error shows up

```
PHP 7.2.5+ is required.

Currently installed version is: ' . PHP_VERSION . '
'); } // phpcs:disable PSR1.Files.SideEffects define('PHPMYADMIN', true); // phpcs:enable require_once ROOT_PATH . 'libraries/constants.php'; /** * Activate autoloader */ if (! @is_readable(AUTOLOAD_FILE)) { die( '

File ' . AUTOLOAD_FILE . ' missing or not readable.
' . '

Most likely you did not run Composer to ' . '' . 'install library files.
> require AUTOLOAD_FILE; global $route, $containerBuilder, $request; Common::run(); $dispatcher = Routing::getDispatcher(); Routing::callControllerForRoute($request, $route, $dispatcher, $containerBuilder);
```

I also tried downloading the file from phpmyadmin website but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This happens, since your php version is not compatible with the phpmyadmin's minimum required version of php.

To solve this issue you can do two different things:

1. Upgrade your php version to something later than 7.2.5.
2. Uninstall your phpmyadmin and install an older version of it.

Comment: I have version 8.2.4 though. Phpmyadmin is not recognizing it.

Comment: You need to check the one which phpmyadmin uses actually. You can have multiple php versions in your computer and the settings in phpmyadmin uses the older version of it. The error says that the "used" php version is below 7.2.5 that is why it cannot properly execute the code.

Comment: How do I do that? I cannot even open the phpmyadmin page. I used the php -v command in terminal and it says php 8.2.4 is in use